# Ionic 2: Importing angular library

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am new to Ionic and Angular, and have found a [library](https://github.com/EricWVGG/AngularSlideables) I'd like to use in my ionic app.  I have placed the .js file in `/src/assets/angular_slideables.js` and have tried to link to it in my `index.html`, but I get the following error:

```
Runtime Error
angular is not defined
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/angular_slideables.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

It was my understanding that angular was already included when I first started my app.  Do I need to link to it anyway?

Comment: Can you try to just import the .js in your .ts file?

Comment: That lib is for angular/ionic 1.... try [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-slideable-directive) porting for angular 2

Comment: I would love to be able to just use the short .js code, I'm just not sure how